# Unable to trigger AJAX call from jQuery validate method

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am unable to send the AJAX request for form submission with the below code. Also I am getting 'Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json' message on my console. I read and tried many of the fixes for similar issue on stack overflow but none of them had worked for me. Also in in request header MIME is set to 'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded'.

```
submitHandler: function(element) {
        var ajaxform = $(element),
            url = ajaxform.attr('action'),
            type = ajaxform.attr('method'),
            data = {};

        $(ajaxform).find('[name="submit"]').html('<i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-fw"></i> Sending...');


        ajaxform.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
            var field = $(this),
                name = field.attr('name'),
                value = field.val();

            data[name] = value;

        });

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'post',
            data: data,
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.type == 'success') {
                    $("#contactForm").before("<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'><a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</a>" + response.text + "</div>");
                    $(ajaxform).each(function() {
                        this.reset();
                        $(this).find('[name="submit"]').html('<i class="fa fa-paper-plane fa-fw"></i> Send');
                    }).find('.valid').each(function() {
                        $(this).remove('label.valid');
                    })
                } else if (response.type == 'error') {
                    $("#contactForm").before("<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'><a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</a>" + response.text + "</div>");
                    $(ajaxform).find('[name="submit"]').html('<i class="fa fa-paper-plane fa-fw"></i> Send');
                }
            }
        });

       return false; 
    }
```

Comment: Are you by chance making a cross-domain request?

Comment: @Todd No,This is the website I am working on and facing this issue www.shreemotors.co.in/one-page.html

Comment: What if you try serializing the data instead of creating an Array with it?
For example: data.serialize();

Comment: @sm1215 Nope didn't work out. I see the 'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded' in request header, is this causing some trouble?